# Salesforce Community issue when template is switched to VF + Tab (that /s)

Tags: lightning, community, url

So we have this community setup that was previously using Napili template.

We switched template to VF + Tab, but the **/s** (i.e. /mycommunity/s) for lightning is still accessible?

How can I get rid of this **/s** ? Or behave it like it never had a lightning template?

Here are the sample to illustrate this situation:

1. [site1](https://secret-one-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/site1) = Using VF+Tabs, and never had any site/lightning
   template.
2. [site2](https://secret-one-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/site2) = Was using Napili template. Now it is using
   VF+Tabs template.

You see, when you access [site 1 with /s](https://secret-one-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/site1/s), it returns with expected result.

But when you access [site 2 with /s](https://secret-one-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/site2/s), the old lightning site which I intend to replace with VF+Tab is being still presented/served, which could create confusion to my users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default Salesforce is going to reserve both the `/mycommunity` and `/mycommunity/s` urls. This is also visible by going to `Setup --> Custom URLs`. Here you can see that the `/mycommunity` has a site type of Force.com while the `/mycommunity/s` has a site type of Site.com.

Both are reserved because you might want to switch between the two different site types but still keep the underlying "mycommunity" name. If you're still utilizing the VF + Tabs in the site builder then I believe this will still utilize the `/s`. If you go with only VF pages and don't utilize the Site Builder Studio then you can utilize just the `/mycommunity` url.

Comment: I know all communities would have /s provisioned in them. But for communities that never had any of the template i.e. Napili, Identity, etc., when you access /s, you will get an invalid url error or something to that effect. but when a template is previously applied and you switch to just VF + Tab, and you try to access ../s, the previously activated template is still there.